# JavaScript Regex for Code Fencing in Markdown

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I'm trying to add support into showdown.js for code fencing, but I'm still sort of a noob at regex. Code fencing, if you don't know, is like this:

````
```javascript
alert('hello world');
```
````

Then it'd create something like:

```
<div class="highlight">
  <pre lang="javascript">
    alert('hello world');
  </pre>
</div>
```

How do I go about capturing ```(anything)\n(anything)``` in JavaScript flavored regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

````
r = /`{3}(?:(.*$)\n)?([\s\S]*)`{3}/m;
r.exec(yourSampleString); // => [..., "javascript", "alert('hello world');\n"]
r.exec('```puts "ok"```'); // => [..., undefined, "puts \"ok\""]
r.exec('```foo```bar```'); // => [..., undefined, "foo```bar"]
````

Comment: Close, but if you noticed my regex needs to capture the `lang=""` parameter. So: `[...,"javascript","alert('hello world')"]`

Comment: @OscarGodson: gotcha, added an optional capture for the language identifier.

Comment: What if there are multiple codes like '```foo``` random ```foo1```' ? It won't be detecting both separately. Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This will get an array of everything between

> ```

```
result = subject.match(/`{3}[\s\S]*?`{3}/g);
```

But beware that nested:

> ```

will be trouble..

Comment: anyway to just ignore all \``` between the first and last \```?

Comment: @OscarGodson You can make the quantifier *? greedy *.